# spy on jquery ui widget in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a jquery ui widget defined like this:

```
$.widget("ui.someWidget",
  options: {}, _create = function() { doSomething(); 
});
```

Now i tried to spy on it like that:

```
var ui_spy = spyOn($.fn, "someWidget");
$('#something').someWidget();
expect(ui_spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

var ui_spy = spyOn($.ui, "someWidget");
$('#something').someWidget();
expect(ui_spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Both return false... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expectation needs to reference a method on the spy:

`expect(ui_spy.someWidget).toHaveBeenCalled();`